# Jquery Regex to find Sentence matching in htmlstring

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I want to find match for "Original cost basis $0.5 million" and replace it with wrapping span tag around it. Text will appear inside any tag like td, font etc. Just find it and wrap with span?

String:

```js
var str = '<td><font style="font: 8pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif">Original cost basis <b>$0.5</b> million</font></td>';
```

Expected result :

```js
'<td><font style="font: 8pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif"><span>Original cost basis <b>$0.5</b> million<span></font></td>'
```

Comment: Have you tried some `regexp`s yourself? If not, try to build one on pages like [regexr](https://regexr.com/) or [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a regex solution but there is also the `replace()` method.

```js
var str = '<td><font style="font: 8pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif">Original cost basis $0.5 million</font></td>';
var res = str.replace("Original cost basis $0.5 million", "My new replacement")

console.log(res);
```

The `replace()` method works like so:

`replace('string to find', 'string that is used to replace the found string');`

W3 Documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Comment: yes true, but i want to build a function like this.
var replaceVal = "Original cost basis $0.5 million";
cellHtmlString = cellHtmlString.replace(regex , function (_match, _preMatch, _postMatch) {
                        
                        return _preMatch + '<span>' + replaceVal + '</span>' + _postMatch;
                    });

Comment: no...replace not works if text contains more tag inside ...Like this


'<td><font style="font: 8pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif">Original cost basis <b>$0.5</b> million</font></td>'

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.replace()` method:

```
var str = '<td><font style="font: 8pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif">Original cost basis $0.5 million</font></td>';
var res = str.replace(/(<td><font.*>)(.*)(<\/font><\/td>)/, '$1<span>$2</span>$3');
```

The above code snippet matches the opening `td` and `font` tags, whatever is inside the font tags, and places them in a 'group' referenced by `$1`. Then, it inserts the `span` tag. Then it puts in the string you are trying to wrap with `span`s, referenced by `$2`. Then it inserts the closing `/span` tag. Finally, it places the closing `/font` and '/td' tags at the end, referenced by `$3`.

Before match:

```
<td><font style="font: 8pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif">Original cost basis $0.5 million</font></td>
```

Post-match and replace:

```
<td><font style="font: 8pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif"><span>Original cost basis $0.5 million</span></font></td>
```

Link to Mozilla documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

Comment: Sentence not always in td ,font tag it will come anywhere inside any tag, I just want to find and wrap it with span.

Comment: As of right now, the question does not describe these points, and hence does not contain enough information. Can you please fix this, so we can better understand the problem, and help find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on my previous answer, it seems the problem is not what I read, and the HTML can't really be guaranteed to be in this structure.

Instead, I will assume the string is in the leaf (lowest part) of the HTML tree. Try this:

```
str.replace(/>([^<]+)</, '<span>$1<\span>');
```

Comment: the regex matching open close tag also....it works for me now by doing this...str.replace(/>([^<]+)</, '><span>$1<\span><');

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = '<td><font style="font: 8pt arial, helvetica, sans-serif">Original cost basis $0.5 million</font></td>';
var replacetext= str.replace(/Original cost basis $0.5 million/g, "New text");

alert(replacetext);
document.write(replacetext);
```